# How to apply animation in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to add `animation` to this `search bar`.
when the user touches the search bar it size decreases and again increases and gets to its default size(like animation in popups)

[image]

This is my code

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row',alignSelf:'center'}}>
        <TextInput
           
          onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
          onFocus={()=>{
            setSize('92%');
            setInterval(()=>{setSize('95%')},1000)
            }}
          placeholder="Search"
          style={{...styles.searchbox,width:size}}     
                             
        ></TextInput>   
 </View>
```

I am currently trying to change width..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest you to take a look at RN animated documentation, maybe it will help you to understand better how the animations work.

Also, it depends on what you're having there: a class component or a function component.
If you're using a function component, you could do it like this:

1. Creating a custom hook, called, let's say `useAnimation()`, which would look something like this

```js
export const useAnimation = ({ doAnimation, duration, initialValue, finalValue }) => {
  const [animation, setAnimation] = useState(new Animated.Value(initialValue))

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.spring(animation, {
      toValue: doAnimation ? initialValue : finalValue,
      duration,
      bounciness: 8,
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start();
  }, [doAnimation]);

  return animation
}
```

2. As it is said in the documentation, you could animate only `Animated` components, and for example if you want to have an animated `View`, the tag will be `<Animated.View> {...} </Animated.View`, but for the `<TextInput>` we have to create the animated component:

```js
  const AnimatedTextInput = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TextInput)
```

and combining the first 2 steps

```js
const AnimatedTextInput = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TextInput)
const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true)
 const animation = useAnimation({ doAnimation: collapsed, duration: 300, initialValue: 20, finalValue: 200 });

  const onFocusText = () => setWidth(false)
  return (
      <AnimatedTextInput
        onFocus={onFocusText}
        placeholder={"Search something"}
        style={{width: animation, height: 50, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 4, padding: 10}}
      />
      )
```

Also, if you're having a class component, you could have a method which will start the animation (but don't forget about the step `2` which is essential)

```js
  private size: Animated.Value = new Animated.Value(COLLAPSED_VALUE)


  get resizeInputWidth(): Animated.CompositeAnimation {
    return Animated.timing(this.size, {
      toValue: EXPANDED_VALUE,
      duration: 500,
    })
  }
  
  startAnimation = () => this.resizeInputWidth.start()
  
  
  <AnimatedTextInput
      onFocus={this.startAnimation}
      style={{ width: this.size }}
  />
```